# BLPAPI and IndexOutOfRangeException will stop to process other events

Tags: python, blpapi

Out of nowhere randomly I'm getting error below when running Python version of the BLPAPI library

```
async-events-app    | Exception in event handler:
async-events-app    | Traceback (most recent call last):
async-events-app    |   File "/usr/src/app/./async-events.py", line 218, in processEvent
async-events-app    |     return self.processSubscriptionDataEvent(event)
async-events-app    |   File "/usr/src/app/./async-events.py", line 145, in processSubscriptionDataEvent
async-events-app    |     bid = msg.getElementAsString("BID")
async-events-app    |   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/blpapi/message.py", line 275, in getElementAsString
async-events-app    |     return self.asElement().getElementAsString(name)
async-events-app    |   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/blpapi/element.py", line 920, in getElementAsString
async-events-app    |     return self.getElement(name).getValueAsString()
async-events-app    |   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/blpapi/element.py", line 742, in getValueAsString
async-events-app    |     _ExceptionUtil.raiseOnError(res[0])
async-events-app    |   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/blpapi/exception.py", line 147, in raiseOnError
async-events-app    |     _ExceptionUtil.raiseException(errorCode, description)
async-events-app    |   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/blpapi/exception.py", line 139, in raiseException
async-events-app    |     raise errorClass(description, errorCode)
async-events-app    | blpapi.exception.IndexOutOfRangeException: Attempt to access an empty scalar element 'BID' (0x0005000b)
```

for corresponding piece of the code for line 218 below

```
if event.eventType() == blpapi.Event.SUBSCRIPTION_DATA:
   return self.processSubscriptionDataEvent(event)
```

where related code for the line 145 is

```
def processSubscriptionDataEvent(self, event):
...

  # Assume all values are scalar.
  event_type = msg.getElementAsString("MKTDATA_EVENT_TYPE")
  event_subtype = msg.getElementAsString("MKTDATA_EVENT_SUBTYPE")

  if event_type == "QUOTE":
    if event_subtype == "BID":
       bid = msg.getElementAsString("BID")
       _logger.info("%s: %s" % (timeStamp, msg.messageType()))
       _logger.info("Trading Symbol: %s" % cInfo.getTopic())
       _logger.info("Bid price: %s " % bid)
```

It looks like for some reason incoming event type is BID but then library should to return an element which should be scalar but it comes as empty even reaching my code.

My question is if there is a way to log what exactly is causing it (my code or Bloomberg library) or is there any way to skip that event w/o throwing that particular exception and move on with the code to continue with rest of subscriptions?

Comment: Probably a security with no bid. You should probably check that the content is a number before parsing.

Comment: @assylias yeah but it happens in the `self.asElement().getElementAsString(name)`  located in `/usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/blpapi/message.py` so is out of my reach and if the the event says subtype is BID BLPAPI should to return BID but instead will throw that exception. There are securities with no bid which event will be simple skipped as subtype is not set as BID

Comment: I don't use that library but you could maybe send a bug report.

Answer (score 1):

Not an answer, but some logging code I used once that I thought might help. My notes to myself say to put this before your session creation and it should print the logging.

```
import blpapi.logging
def callback(threadId, severity, dt, category, message):
    print(threadId, severity, dt, category, message)

BLP_LOGGER = blpapi.logging.Logger.registerCallback(
    callback,
    thresholdSeverity=blpapi.logging.Logger.SEVERITY_INFO
)
```

Severity levels:

```
SEVERITY_OFF
SEVERITY_FATAL
SEVERITY_ERROR
SEVERITY_WARN
SEVERITY_INFO
SEVERITY_DEBUG
SEVERITY_TRACE
```

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if it is the condition you are hitting, but the docs say that BID can be null in some cases. Like maybe after market hours it is reporting a NULL value. I think the safe way to access it would be:

```
       bid = msg.getElement("BID")
       _logger.info("%s: %s" % (timeStamp, msg.messageType()))
       _logger.info("Trading Symbol: %s" % cInfo.getTopic())
       _logger.info("Bid price: %s " % ("" if bid.isNull() else bid.getValueAsString()))
```